# Deploy multiple WSPs to specific web application or globally in MOSS 2007 environment

Tags: 2007, solution-deployment

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity $solutionName -WebApplication $webApp -GacDeployment -Force
```

But I get cmdlet not found error. Please can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2007 you should use STSADM as the powershell cmdlets wasn't introduced until 2010.

See [Addsolution: Stsadm operation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263162(v=office.12).aspx) and [Deploysolution: Stsadm operation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262459(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PowerShell instead of Cmd, then you need to [load sharepoint assemblies first](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/01/22/running-powershell-on-moss-2007.aspx).

1. To add a solution to the Farm solution store use the Add-SPSolution cmdlet:

   ```
   Add-SPSolution –LiteralPath "C:DeploymentMySharePointSolutionPackage.wsp"
   ```
2. To install a Farm Solution use the Install-SPSolution cmdlet:

   ```
   Install-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolutionPackage.wsp –WebApplication http://webapplication –GACDeployment
   ```